# Combine two columns and input the result in a different columns using SQL server

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

Please can anyone help me with the insert sql statement below.  I am trying to create a SampleID by combining column ID (auto generate by the database) and the MBID column. I am having the error 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Thanks

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"insert into Sample (MBID, SampleType,SampleDate,ConsultantName,Comments,FirstSample, SampleID) 
values(@MBID , @SampleType , @SampleDate , @ConsultantName , @Comments,  CONCAT(ID +'-'+ MBID) ;", con);


Table Design

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample] (
[ID]             INT            IDENTITY (5, 1) NOT NULL,
[SampleID]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[SampleType]     NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[SampleDate]     DATE           NULL,
[ConsultantName] NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Comments]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[FirstSample]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[MBID]           INT            NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Sample] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SampleID] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, CONCAT was introduced in SQL Server 2012

Using CONCAT function:

```
SELECT CONCAT ( 'Welcome ', 'World ', '!' ) AS Result;
```

Secondly, you want auto generated value to be concatenated to the id value for the sample Id column. The below query can be used for that...

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table_name')+1;
```

Now, alter your query as below

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"insert into Sample (MBID, SampleType,SampleDate,ConsultantName,Comments,FirstSample, SampleID) 
values(@MBID , @SampleType , @SampleDate , @ConsultantName , @Comments,  cast((IDENT_CURRENT('Sample')+1) as VARCHAR(max)) +'-'+ CAST(@MBID AS VARCHAR(10)));", con);
```

Comment: Thanks Worked I am using Sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)</kbd> is available from SQLServer 2012..use `+` instead

Also remeber ,you might have to use `ISNULL` to avoid nulls,Since `CONCAT` ignores nulls

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings in `SQL-server`, you could either use the `CONCAT` function, or `+`. You are trying to do both.

The `CONCAT` function takes at least 2 comma-separated arguments.

So, either

```
ID +'-'+ MBID
```

Or

```
CONCAT(ID, '-', MBID)
```

Comment: Thanks Tobb. I tried this     insert into Sample (MBID, SampleType, SampleDate,ConsultantName,Comments,FirstSample, SampleID) 
values('2088' , 'PB' , '2000-09-29' , 'CSC' , 'SEE TA FOR STORAGE lpd ref','YES', ID +'-'+ MBID ); I am having  the error Invalid column name 'ID'. and MBID I am using SQL server 2008

Comment: Might be missing a `@` or something? You have `@MBID` somewhere else, don't know if you have defined `@ID` anywhere..

Comment: ID is auto generate by the database  [ID]   INT IDENTITY (5, 1) NOT NULL

Comment: You can't use the autogenerated id as part of the insert statement. You could ommit the column from insert and then run an update after you are done inserting though.

Comment: Though I must say it's unusal not to use the identity column as primary key.